# Cors not working for me in istio version 1.20.2

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

When I configured Cors policy in Virtual service it allowing all the origins. not blocking other origins. frontend app only to be access for that added allow origin as front end endpoint.

here is my configuration file.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: site-api-vser
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - app-istio-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: site-svc.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 5100
      corsPolicy:
        allowOrigin:
          - http://x.x.x.x:32675
        allowOrigins:
          - exact: http://x.x.x.x:32675
        allowMethods:
          - POST
          - GET
          - PUT
          - OPTIONS
          - PATCH
          - DELETE
        allowHeaders:
          - authorization
          - content-type
          - accept
          - origin
          - user-agent
```